# Upgrading node version doesn't effect previous node js projects

Tags: node.js

I have to upgrade nodejs version for new project, but i am not sure, as my previous projects are running on node version 6 or less. So will they be affected (meaning functionality wise), if i upgrade nodejs to new version?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which version they were created. As [Node.js documentation](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/) stands:

> **Minor releases**:
>
> Do not generally change APIs nor introduce backwards-incompatible breaking changes, except where unavoidable.
>
> **Major releases**:
>
> Usually introduce backwards-incompatible, breaking changes.

You have to check which version were you using and compare to current one.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a new major version of node might introduce backwards incomptible changes, but that doesn’t mean your projects won’t run.

You can go over the [node releases](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) and check the changelogs, see if something catches your eyes, depending on which version you want to upgrade to. You’re the only one who knows tour projects and their complexity, and can decide if it’s worth to upgrade.